# xhr request 404 node and react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, reactjs, express

I am making a simple login page in react which should get connected to a database by an ajax call to a node js file.

This is the node js code that I have:

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var db=require('./db');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var server=require('http').Server(app);
app.set('port',process.env.PORT||8080);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('views','views');
app.set('view engine','html');

app.use(express.static('./public'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended:true
}))

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.post('/newuser',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body.username);
    console.log(req.body.password);
})
```

And the ajax call from the react file looks something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';
import {MusicApp} from './music-app.js';

class Signup extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            isLoggedin:false
        }

        this.changePage=this.changePage.bind(this);
    }
    changePage(){

        var username=document.getElementById('username').value;
        var password=document.getElementById('password').value;
        var that=this;
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/newuser',
            data:{
                username:username,
                password:password
            },
            success:function(){
                that.setState({
                    isLoggedin:true
                })
            }
        })

    }
    render(){
        if(this.state.isLoggedin){
            return(
                <MusicApp/>
                )
        }else{
            return(
                <div>
                <input type='text' id='username' placeholder='username'/>
                <input type='password' id='password' placeholder='password'/>
                <input type='button' id='signup' value='Signup' onClick={this.changePage}/>
                </div>

                )
        }
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Signup />,document.getElementById('container'));
```

index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        todo-app 
    </title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;," type="image/x-icon">   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"> </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/build/vendors.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/build/musicApp.bundle.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

So, when I run the whole code on port number 8080, it gives me a 404 for xhr request not found.
The folder structure that I have is something like this:
[image: here] The ajax call is being made from signup.js. I have already done `npm install --save express` and `npm install --save body-parser`

What am I missing?

Comment: The folder structure doesn't matter because it doesn't map directly onto the URL structure. The URL of the JS doesn't matter because browsers make requests relative to the page, not the script loaded into the page. The code shows that it should be requesting /newuser and the server looks like it should host /newusers … so you need to figure out where it is breaking down. Don't just look at the status code. Look at the request of the request and response. Is the browser requesting the URL you expect? Is it going to the right server? Does the server log show it coming in to the right path?

Comment: I am getting the 404 in my bundle.js file. so I am guessing that something is wrong with the whole ajax request @Quentin

Comment: Does a GET work to the same url?

Comment: @terpinmd — There's no get handler registered for it

Comment: @aayushi — What bundle.js? There's no mention of that in the question. It doesn't appear in your file system screenshot. Does it contain your changePage function? If that function isn't loading, it can't make an Ajax request, so the request you say is giving you a 404 is never made so can't get any response.

Comment: Your Node code doesn't appear to do *anything*. It looks like the call to `app.listen` is missing. You should provide a real [mcve].

Comment: @Quentin I am sure he can figure out how to register one.

Comment: I havent checked with a get request @terpinmd

Comment: I would try it cause you can copy and paste url in the browser.....also try a fully qualified url just for fun.  Probably a small issue your overlooking.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you express server is not listening to any port, It has set the port, Its not listening on it.

Try with this

```
const express=require('express');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const db = require('./db');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


app.set('views', 'views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(express.static('./public'));

app.post('/newuser', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.username);
    console.log(req.body.password);
    res.send({postedUserName: req.body.username});
});

if (!module.parent) {
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Your application starts listening at Port ${PORT}`);
  });
}
```